# de Rham isomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, de-rham-cohomology

Let $X$ be an open manifold, with one end $N$,

**Q** How to show that $H^1_{c,dR}(X)\to H^1_{dR}(X)$ is an injective,?
here $H^1_{dR}$ denotes the de Rham cohomology and $H^1_{c,dR}$ denotes the compactly supported de Rham cohomology.

Suppose that $H^1(N;\mathbb R)=0$.

**Q** How to show that $H^1_{c,dR}(X)\cong H^1_{dR}(X)$?